# NodeJS|Cluster Are process.send and worker.send blocking? If so, what's the performance?

Tags: performance, node.js, cluster-computing, synchronous

I have 2 questions.

1. Are the process.send and worker.send functions blocking?  And what is the performance of this type of inter-process communication?
2. I have a cluster which has the master pushing updates to the worker and the workers pushing aggregated data to the master.  However, there's a particular query where I need the latest data from the master.  When the request comes in on the worker, I store the "response" object, then do a process.send() to contact the master for the most recent data, then on the master, I get the data then do a worker.send() to send back the data.  I pass a responseId back and forth so that when the request finally comes back, I know which response to write back to and then call the end() function on it.

Is there a better way to do synchronous calls like this between processes?  It doesn't happen very often, but what kind of performance implications will come from this with regard to all the other non-blocking requests that are happening?  Will it hold everything else up?  Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> Are the process.send and worker.send functions blocking

No.

> And what is the performance of this type of inter-process communication

Mostly the same as JSON serialization / deserialization. The data transfer is handled by the OS and is pretty fast.

> Is there a better way to do synchronous calls like this between processes?

Not in node.

> It doesn't happen very often, but what kind of performance implications will come from this with regard to all the other non-blocking requests that are happening

Not significant. Its like querying a database ... while the database goes and does its job the web process is free to respond to other requests. Same principal here (master -> worker).